# dict with one key and multiple values

Tags: python

I was wondering if there's a way for me to pull a value at a specific index. Let's say I have a key with multiple values associated with it. But in my dictionary I have multiple keys, each key with multiple values. I want to iterate through the keys and then each respective value associated with that key. I want to be able to pull the value at the first index and subtract it from the value at the second index.

```
d= {108572791: [200356.77, 200358], 108577388: [19168.7, 19169]}

output for key 108572791 would be -1.33
output for key 108577388 would be -.03
```

I've try reading up on dict and how it works apparently you can't really index it. I just wanted to know if there's a way to get around that.

```
for key, values in total_iteritems():
    for value in values:
       value[0]-value[1]:
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Please add your attempt and the expected output to your question.

Comment: Assuming all values in your dictionary have two elements, you could iterate over your dict with something like `for key, (first, second) in d.items():`

Comment: Put down the things you've tried and what the expected output is, in the form of samples, instead of a paragraph. That would help make better sense of the problem statement.

Comment: sorry I just added the code

Comment: What is your expected output? Please, edit the question to include it.

Comment: i updated post sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Edit:

Since the question is way different now, I'll address the new subject:

```
d= {108572791: [200356.77, 200358], 108577388: [19168.7, 19169]}
for i in d:
    print("Output for key ",str(i), "would be ",(d[i][1]-d[i][0]))
```

Output:

```
Output for key  108572791 would be  1.2300000000104774
Output for key  108577388 would be  0.2999999999992724
```

#### Original answer

Yes. When you have a `dict` containing a **list** as `value` if you want to obtain a specific value, then you need to address the index in the list. An example is:

```
a = {'Name':['John','Max','Robert']}
```

This means that:

```
print(a['Name'])
```

Output:

```
['John','Max','Robert']
```

Since ['Name'] is a list:

```
for i in range(len(a['Name'])):
    print(a['Name'][i]
```

Output:

```
John #(Because it's the index 0)
Max #(Index = 1)
Robert #(Index = 2)
```

If you want a specific value (for instance 'Max' which is index = 1)

```
print(a['Name'][1]
```

Output:

```
Max
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how many values in key obvious but this does the trick:

```
for x in d:
        print(x)
        print(d[x][0]-d[x][1])
```

Comment: what should i do if i have alot of values in one key? is there a way to iterate through those keys and chose them at a certain index?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list of tuples if you want to use indexing.

> d= [(108572791,[200356.77, 200358]), (108577388,[19168.7, 19169)]

```
for tuple in my_list:
   print(tuple[0]) 
   for value in tuple[1]:
       print(value)
```